# LabelKFold Sklearn Cross Validation - What does the doc mean by label?

Tags: scikit-learn, cross-validation

I know there have been questions posted here on this topic and I've read the documentation several times over, but I'm still having a hard time understanding how Sklearn's LabelKFold CV works. In particular, what is meant by the label? Is it the row index? If someone has the patience to write back and explain I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: See the documentation [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/cross_validation.html#label-k-fold)

Comment: Hi @ali_m, that's the documentation I was referring to in my post. I'm not sure what the doc means by label. Is it supposed to be a class label, row index or what?

Comment: `labels` is just an array with the same length as your `X` and `y` arrays. The interpretation depends on what your specific application is. A typical use-case discussed in the documentation above is where you have data from multiple subjects, and you want to avoid including data from the same subject in both your training and test sets since this might lead to overfitting. In that case `labels` would be a vector of integers where each unique integer corresponds to a different subject.

Comment: Hi @ali_m, thanks for the responses.  The use case you are describing is what I'm attempting to do. So my question is how, in the example code given in the document, the labels for the subjects (1,2,3) are denoted in the X array. If it was a pandas dataframe this would be in the index. But of course we're dealing with a numpy array. How does the algorithm know which row applies to which subject?

Comment: Ok, I figured it out based on your last comment. Thanks for the help.